# Can sys_execve() still return with error after begin_new_exec() returns zero?

Tags: linux-kernel, exec, ebpf, kprobe

I'm using a BPF kprobe to find out when a task's UIDs, GIDs and namespaces change outside the syscalls that have the ability to change these values. For this, I update `values[pid]` when returning from `execve()`, `execveat()`, `setns()`, `unshare()`, `set*uid()`. And on entry to `begin_new_exec()`, I check whether the current task's values match `values[pid]`.

In some cases the probes incorrectly report that the UID or nsproxy for a process has changed, indicating I've missed a place where I need to update the task's values.

Looking at `begin_new_exec()`, it replaces the task's credentials and wipes out the old executable. But after `begin_new_exec()` returns, `load_elf_binary()` can still return errors while trying to set up the new process image.

Do these late errors reach usermode ? Is there a scenario where `sys_execve` can fail after `begin_new_exec` returns, and the PID is not terminated ?

Comment: The [comment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/exec.c#L1238) above `begin_new_exec()` states *"Calling this is the point of no return. None of the failures will be seen by userspace"*... so there's that.

Comment: Seems like the answer does lie in the point of no return. Once bprm->point_of_no_return is set in begin_new_exec, any errors returned in bprm_execve result in a fatal signal being sent.